# UseSelector returns me undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

A little context:

I’m trying to transform a class with redux component to a hooks component (Bosses orders), in this process I read about a way to transform a `mapStateToProps` to `useSelector`, so I’m trying to give it a go, but I’ve been having a problem lately with

```
const favValues = useSelector(favourites => favourites.favValues);
```

the same code in case the writing isn’t clear.

because it returns undefined.

I guess the real question would be how I transform this

```
function mapStateToProps({ queryFilter, favourites }) {
    return {
      queryFilter : queryFilter,
      //Favourites:
      favValues : favourites.favValues,
      defaultGroup : favourites.defaultGroup,
      initialValues : favourites.initialValues,
      favouritesList : favourites.favouritesList,
      loadingFavValues : favourites.loadingFavValues,
      applyingFavValues : favourites.applyingFavValues,
    }
  }
```

To `useSelector`.

Any help or bibliography would be most appreciated

Comment: Are you using the `react-redux` package?

Comment: See my answer below, hope it helps. If so, please mark it as the correct answer. If you have any other questions, feel free to comment on the post

Comment: Yes, I am using the react-redux package

Comment: I am still being unable to get the same info i would get if I used this.props.favValues

Comment: is `favValues` undefined in your reducer?

Comment: Supposedly starts as undefined, then it becomes an empty {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to use mapStateToProps

So `mapStateToProps` has `state` as a parameter.

Usually I write it like this:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
     return {
         favValues: state.favorites.favValues,
          // etc..
     }
}
```

You've just deconstructed it, But here state = `{ queryFilter, favorites}`.

### How to use useSelector

With `useSelector`, it also receives state in the callback, so your hook should look like this:

`const favorites = useSelector(state => state.favorites.favValues);`

OR I suppposed you could descontruct that state again to look like this:

`const favorites = useSelector(({favorites})=> favorites.favValues);`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, though it still returns me undefined, it was clear my code was bad written

Comment: If you want to paste code of your action and reducer we can look at that too